# Large inconsistency between Yelp v2 API queries and equivalent searches on Yelp.com

Tags: python, yelp

Search results using the Yelp v2 API look very different from what you'd find on their website

For example, on the website:

http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=restaurants&find_loc=Manhattan%2C+NY&ns=1#start=0&sortby=rating

I issued the same search using their API after reading their documentation, with the following Python code

```
import json

import argparse
import json
import pprint
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2

import oauth2

HOST = 'api.yelp.com'
PATH = '/v2/search/'

# I put my account's values here, leaving blank for the question
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
TOKEN = ''
TOKEN_SECRET = ''

def main():
    url_params = {
        'term': 'restaurants',
        'location': 'Manhattan,NY',
        'sort': 2, # sort by "Highest Rated"
    }

    url = 'http://{0}{1}?'.format(HOST, PATH)

    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(
        CONSUMER_KEY, 
        CONSUMER_SECRET
    )
    oauth_request = oauth2.Request(
        method="GET", 
        url=url, 
        parameters=url_params
    )

    oauth_request.update(
        {
            'oauth_nonce': oauth2.generate_nonce(),
            'oauth_timestamp': oauth2.generate_timestamp(),
            'oauth_token': TOKEN,
            'oauth_consumer_key': CONSUMER_KEY
        }
    )
    token = oauth2.Token(TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET)
    oauth_request.sign_request(
        oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), 
        consumer, 
        token
    )
    signed_url = oauth_request.to_url()
    print 'Querying {0} ...'.format(url)
    conn = urllib2.urlopen(signed_url, None)
    try:
        print conn.read()
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

I tried many different combinations of query parameters (changing the location phrase to include spaces, no comma, etc. also tried introducing a limit and offset), but with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Results of the API query are here https://code.stypi.com/cmqnfxuo

Answer (score 0):

I think issue may be on path.Here your code

```
PATH = '/v2/search/'
```

So your reguest url like this.

```
http://api.yelp.com/v2/search/?
```

Error in your url path. The Search path should be:

```
PATH = '/v2/search'
```

The request url will be changed like this:

```
 http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=San+Francisco
```

[More information](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api)